# How to validate both fields at the same time when changing one of them, and only display error message if both fields are not empty?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, yup

I have a situation: firstname and lastname can't all be empty.When all of them are empty,all fields show error,but when one of them is not emty, there are no error.
I use yup as validator util and react hook form to achieve it.
when all fileds are empty just like this.[snapshot.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxInp.png)

But When i change onevalue,the other's error is still existed
[snapshot2.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyCJp.png)

Only triggering the blur event of the other input by myself can make the error disappear.
[snapshot3.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCy8Z.png)

How can i manually trigger specified field's rule when change it's dependencing field value?
This is code example :
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/yup-form-test-fvg8m2?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx

has described on above

Comment: Just add required() in both first name and last name in SignupSchema and it will show an error if any one of those is empty.

Comment: Code Link: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-hooks-counter-demo-forked-tt9x4l?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.js%3A24%2C16